# Navigating to a specific screen from Drawer Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am building a small portfolio using three navigators i.e stack, drawer and materialbottomtab. Following are the sections I want to have in the portfolio: home screen, projects screen, skills screen, about screen and hire screen. In my material tab navigator I have all the screens except the about screen. In the drawer navigator, I have all the 5 screens. My home and project screen are being used as stack screens. When I click on the project screen from my drawer navigator, it takes me to the screen but there is no header like in case of home screen.

```
function HamburgerMenu() {
   <Drawer.Navigator> 
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={MainTabNavigator}/>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Projects" component={//Project screen of MainTabNavigator} />
   </Drawer.Navigator>
}
```

The maintabnavigator is a function which has bottom tab navigator in it just like above. How can I navigate to the project screen of maintabnavigator (without losing header) from drawer navigator.

Answer (score 1):

Because, a header is part of Stack navigator. So if you want it at your project screen, you will have to add StackNavigator into your screen.

You could either put a stack inside tab, or tab inside stack which depends on your use case.

I created an example in snack here https://snack.expo.io/@gie3d/drawer-tab-stack

From the snack example link, you will see the tab bar with stack and without stack and how it is displayed.

```js
const HomeStack = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

const TabWithoutStack = () => (
  <Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen name="HomeTabWithoutStack1" component={Home} />
    <Tab.Screen name="HomeTabWithoutStack2" component={Home} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
)

const TabWithStack = () => (
  <Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen name="HomeTabWithStack1" component={HomeStack} />
    <Tab.Screen name="HomeTabWithStack2" component={HomeStack} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
)

const Home = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
  <View>
    <Text>This is Home</Text>
    <Button onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
      Open Drawer
    </Button>
  </View>
)}

export default () => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeStack">
          <Drawer.Screen name="HomeStack" component={HomeStack} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="HomeNoStack" component={Home} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="TabWithoutStack" component={TabWithoutStack} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="TabWithStack" component={TabWithStack} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  );
}
```